# CSS - Vertical scrollbar at 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page - html, body, .container, and img all have height 100%. html & body have margin & padding of 0px.

I have a long img that gets squeezed into the window (due to height: 100%). But there is a vertical scrollbar on the right. I can't figure out why.

I can force-hide it with `overflow-y: hidden`, but I'd like to know why it is there. (Shows up in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, so it's not a browser bug.)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i2.wp.com/emilcarlsen.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2014/12/20141120_130615.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: white space  ...

Comment: Nop, there is not white spaces. use chrome inspector and you will realize

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz add font-size:0 and the scroll will disappear ;) or add `vertical-align:top` to image also

Comment: @TemaniAfif is right. adding `font-size:0;` solves the problem

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz and to be more precise it's white space overflowing that's why you don't see it in chrome inspector .. so you can also add `overflow:hidden` to container

Comment: I can't recommend `font-size:0`, because there are browsers that will use the minimum font size from the user preferences. (for example, 7px instead of 0.) `vertical-align:top` is better.

Comment: @MrLister - Are there any modern browsers that still don't support font-size:0 ? Although many support a minimum size, most, AFAIK, don't apply that to font-size:0, since it's obvious that such text is not intended to be read at all.

Comment: @MrLister me too i don't recommand font-size:0 .. i simply said to Luis so he can see it's a white space issue :) it's clearly better to consider vertical alignement and also to understand it

Comment: @Alohci Good question. I know this used to be a problem in the past, but I must admit I haven't tested that recently on all currently available browsers.

Comment: The referenced duplicate is correct! Set `img {display: block;}` works perfectly. Thank you!